# What does full path mean with sweaver module?

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and am struggling to learn how it uses CSS. I am not very familiar with CSS. I am using the Outreach theme and the Sweaver module. Sweaver shows a "full path". See image of my full path. [image]

Do each of these items in the path represent different CSS files? If so, where do I find these files? I am trying to remove an underline.

Comment: The items represent the hierarchy of the HTML elements (parent -> child relationships) from outer to inner. So "Body" is the body tag, then there's an element representing the "page-wrapper" region (maybe div/section/etc), and so on until you get down to the element you've selected, a list in this case. I don't know how that applies to the sweaver module, sorry. At a guess, it's going to generate the CSS for you (`body .region-page-wrapper .region-page ... ul` as a contrived example), so you'd be able to toggle the underline on or off with the UI

Comment: Thanks. So to change underlining (or any other attribute) the change should be made at the lowest child level? In other words the lowest child level takes priority over upper parent levels? How can I find the actual files that relate to each of these parent/child levels?

Comment: That's where learning CSS and how to use the browser tools comes in, there's no shortcut for that. The nature of CSS means there isn't a set path to any particular element, there are almost always several ways to target anything. _How_ you're able to target it also depends heavily on context, i.e. what other CSS rules you have applied to the page, and how their [specificity](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20specificity) stacks up against others. The stuff you need to know from here isn't about Drupal, it's all CSS/general web development

Comment: OK. I've spent about a week with this (off & on). I guess I'll have to spend another week or two. This particular aspect of Drupal seems very complex. I am not interested in creating themes. All I want to do is tweak Outreach.

Comment: That should read _This particular aspect of **HTML & CSS** seems very complex_. When you're talking about targeting HTML elements with CSS, you're not talking about anything related to Drupal any more. Drupal just happens to use the industry standard technologies/languages, it doesn't augment or change those technologies. I think one of the reasons you're finding this hard is because you're expecting Drupal to be able to make learning or producing HTML & CSS easier for you - but that's the wrong way round, you need to know those technologies before you can use them to make changes in Drupal